# load google charts through an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I'm trying to call the google chart after clicking on a link. This is what my function looks like:

```
function getGraphData(id) {

    var ajax_url = '<?=URL?>ajaxlibrary/get-graph-data';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax_url,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: ({
            id : id
      }),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('a').removeClass("selected");
            $('#link_'+id).addClass("selected");
            alert(data);

        },
    });
}
```

So what I'm trying to achieve here is to load a different graph for a different like, so lets say I have politics charts, sports charts etc. I don't know where to put the Google API code though, because it seems it's just not working...

EDIT:
I edited the function like this:

```
  $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "html",
         data: {id: id},
         url: '<?=URL?>' + 'ajaxlibrary/get-charts',
         success: function(datas) {
            console.log(datas);
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    datas
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'My Daily Activities'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
         }
    });
```

but i'm having issues with sending this data stream from my ajax php file:

```
echo '[\'Task\', \'Hours per Day\'],
            [\'Work\',     10],
            [\'shit\',     50],
            [\'loop\',     25],
            [\'poop\',     15]';
```

the response is not a valid 2D array. If I put the values in the javascript file manually, it works, so the issue is somewhere in the response.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can load the Google Charts with Ajax call using below code.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.google.com/jsapi?callback',
  cache: true,
  dataType: 'script',
  success: function(){
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], 'callback' : function()
      {

            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: {id: YOURIDHERE},
                 url: '<?=URL?>' + 'ajaxlibrary/get-charts',
                 success: function(jsondata) {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsondata);

                    var options = {title: 'My Daily Activities'};

                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                 }
            });    
        ]);

      }
    });
    return true;
  }
});
```

you can load any other chart types instead of just the corechart using Google API.

Comment: amazing, that worked. One thing though, I want to pass the ID I had in my original ajax, so I can load the specific values from the PHP file. Maybe add another ajax call as it load the data?

Comment: see commented code 
//do your chart creation stuff here

you can add your stuff here.. if charts have no need for your stuff you can do it outside this call as well.\

Comment: I know what you meant, just check out my edited first post and tell me what to do please.

Comment: You can pass the id to that edited ajax call using data parameter

type: "POST",
data: {id: IDHERE},
other stuff as is

Comment: does it have to be a json datatype?

Comment: No, you can get any type of data and convert it to the understandable format of google.visualization.arrayToDataTable function i.e. array.

Comment: although that looks like it should work it doesn't. I changed the data type to html and the response is: Not a valid 2d array. I edited the first post so you can see what i've done

Comment: Nice chainng of loaders. AJAX runs Goole Charts loader, and it when loads fully runs showing graphs. But what if one wants to have two graphs each loaded by ajax. To start google charts loader multiple times?