# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown AJAX call

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to make drop down update a graph which is build by Google Chart API. 
Few issues I have right now.

1. It is sending `request` to a wrong url, instead of `/graph/` it is sending data to the page it is on right now which is `/services/`. So i cant continue debugging it, since it doesnt even send out `POST` to where it is needed. `/graph/`(ajax.py) is the one that contains data for AJAX
2. I know that right now it is not passing down any data, but I wasnt able to figure out even how to access correct view. If 1 is fixed, what would be the best way to pass down value from the drop down menu of twitter bootstrap

#### HTML

Cred goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649001/bootstrap-input-field-and-dropdown-button-submit)

```
<form id="select-graph" name="select-graph" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" formmethod="POST">
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a onclick="$('#select-graph').submit()">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</form>
```

#### AJAX script

Cred goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667772/load-google-charts-through-an-ajax-call)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var graphid = 1;
            $('#select-graph').submit(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://www.google.com/jsapi?callback',
                    cache: true,
                    dataType: 'script',
                    success: function(){
                    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], 'callback' : function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: '/graph/',
                            success: function(jsondata) {
                                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsondata);
                                var options = {title: 'My Daily Activities'};
                                var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                                chart.draw(data, options);
                            }
                        })    
                    }
                  })
                }
            })
            return true
        })  
</script>
```

#### /graph/ - ajax.py

```
def insider_graphs(request):   
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        #code that works, this json.dumps with 
        #special encoder works in all others parts 
        #of the code and charts look fine
        return HttpResponse({'array':json.dumps(data, cls=SpecialEncoder)},  content_type="application/json", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

#### Solution

Based on accepted solution, I had to make small modification to make it work:

`jsondata` item that was being passed had the item I needed inside, so rather than call `jsondata` I needed jsondata['jsondata'], where 'jsondata' is the object name i passed down from django

new line:
`var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsondata['jsondata']);`

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle or smth similar?

Comment: I simplified the drop down menu to a simple drop list. I posted sample chart code there from Google Charts. If you can somehow can make it present a graph, and then changing and option update the graph, would be greatly appreciated. I think that would most of my issues, cheers!

Comment: Didnt post the link but here it is http://jsfiddle.net/XmL2E/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualy you are firering two submits: one posts to `/graph/` (ajax) and the other posts to `/services/` (not ajax). The second one reloads the page.

What you need to change is prevent second submit from triggering. You can archive it by calling `preventDefault()` method of event in submit callbak:

```
$('#select-graph').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.google.com/jsapi?callback',
        cache: true,
    /* rest of your code */
    ....
});
```

**UPDATE**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QY2LA/)

**UPDATE 2: Valid Django view returning json**

```
return HttpResponse(
    json.dumps({'array': data}, cls=SpecialEncoder),
    content_type="application/json",
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

Comment: Added, nothing changed! Thought on unexpected token, maybe thats part of it?

Comment: Fixed unexpected token part, however page still reloads. And yes I am aware of the process, however looking through logs it doesnt seem that `/graph/` is ever engaged. I looked through server logs for `GET` and `POST` requests, not a single `/graph` item

Comment: Might it be that you've placed code called "AJAX script" in `<head>`? If so you'd better wrap it inside `$(document).ready(function() { /* YOUR CODE HERE */ });`

Comment: Negative, it is right at the bottom of `<body>`, in fact next tag after  `</script>` is the `</body>`

Comment: Can't say what you've done wrong or may be something else is inclined but the exact my answer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QY2LA/) works great.

Comment: just open dev tools in browser and see `POST http://fiddle.jshell.net/graph/ 403 (FORBIDDEN)`

Comment: I've fixed your fiddle to the working point http://jsfiddle.net/jLNKr/. Basicaly you a) didn't have `<form id="...">` b) tried to use `google` before loading it c) used `onclick` where should be `onchange` (`<select>` element) and d) didn't incorporate my answer.

Comment: I had an slight error in code, thanks! Appropriate view is being accessed and no errors but my data structure seems to be wrong, any ideas? I've narrowed it to return HttpResponse({'array':json.dumps(data, cls=SpecialEncoder)}, content_type="application/json") part

Comment: Try Update 2 in your backend

Comment: with `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` I get Error 500, and the rest gives me `Uncaught Error: Not an array`. If this helps, I made a fiddle with sample code and data structure
http://jsfiddle.net/3cvP7/

Comment: From I gather ( i looked at many examples), `HttpResponse` doesnt need response. All responses I see have data + content_type, no context. Without it I get no error codes, except in inspect element, as i mentioned `Error: Not an array`. When I used `console.log` on it, item is `Object {jsondata: Array[13]}` and looks fine

Comment: Well, then `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsondata.jsondata);` in your `success: function(jsondata)`